# super of sub function

Tags: java, overriding, subclass, superclass

I have a function in my superclass (`Speler`) that is called `kiesKaart`:

```
public Kaart kiesKaart(int spelerIndex){...}
```

In my subclass function, I have the same function with an other parameter that overrides (i do have `@Override` before it, changing this to `@Override()` does not help...) the super function:

```
public int kiesKaart(Kaart lak){...}
```

In my main I have an array of `Spelers`, where only the first is an `Speler` and the others are `AiSpelers` (this is the name of the subclass):

```
spelerArr[0] = new Speler(hand[0]);
for (int i=1;i<AANTALSPELERS;i++) {
    spelerArr[i] = new AiSpeler(hand[i]);
}
```

Later on in my code I address `spelerArr[i].kiesKaart`, so now I want the code to address the correct instance of `kiesKaart`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're not overriding your baseclass function - you are overloading it. Annotating it makes no difference, it's just a marker for your benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Override` will do nothing here because the two methods are different. The first one returns type `Kaart` given an `int`, and the second returns type `int` given a `Kaart`.

In other words, to make sure you are calling the right method, you need to make sure you send the right parameter (`int` for the first, `Kaart` for the second).

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot, but i still get an error in the main saying that it expects an integer(from the super class) even though i edited the sub to return Kaart as well

Comment: and i am sending the correct parameter in each case. on the first one is doesn't complain, the second one he says he wants an integer

Comment: Is it complaining that you are not sending the correct parameter? or that you are casting the result to a `Kaart` object?

Comment: it was complaining about the parameter, now i (kind of) fixed it by having the exact same parameters in both methods (overriding this time) even though i don't use 1 of the parameters in each case

Comment: ok, i just found this...
In a subclass, you can overload the methods inherited from the superclass. Such overloaded methods neither hide nor override the superclass methods—they are new methods, unique to the subclass.

Comment: so i guess i'll just have to go with the way i solved it :$ thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

The signatures do not match. So you are not overriding the method in super class. The compiler will complain if you use `@Override`. The signature of the method also includes the type of the parameter.

Comment: crap. I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You overloaded the method by creating a new one with the same name and different arguments. Override is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to have to use `instanceof` to determine if it is a `Speler` or `AiSpeler` and cast it to the appropriate object before calling `kiesKaart`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overloading your superclass method, not overriding. Having an annotation does not change this fact.

If you want to determine the type of the calling object (polymorphism) you have to override the method - same parameter list, same return type or a subclass (as of Java 5) and of course the same name.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/overload/overridingMethods.html) might be helpful as a quick reference on what is possible and what not, and how to call it